# Shell Remove lower versions from array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting

I have the following array:

```
ARRAYNAME=(value_1.21.zip value_1.22.zip valueN_0.51.zip valueN_0.52.zip valueM_3.52)
```

I want to remove the lower versions of the same element and to have the following array:

```
ARRAYNAME=(value_1.22.zip valueN_0.52.zip valueM_3.52)
```

In this moment I am using this approach to remove the same elements

```
ARRAYNAMESORT=$(tr ' ' '\n' <<< "${ARRAYNAME[@]}" | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')
```

but I am stuck in removing the lower versions. Does anyone has an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Are the versions limited to just x.xx or it could follow semantic versioning? you have much bigger problem if its the latter

Comment: You should have showed your attempts. This was a good question

Comment: It's  following semantic versioning.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the text structure `[Name]_[version].zip`

```
ARRAYNAME=($(printf '%s\n' "${ARRAYNAME[@]}" | awk '{print $1,$1}' | cut -d'_' -f2- | sort -n | sed  1d | awk '{print $2}' | paste -s))
```

Explanation:

1. print all array elements `printf '%s\n' "${ARRAYNAME[@]}"`
2. duplicate the name in two column `awk '{print $1,$1}'`
3. remove left text from the first column `cut -d'_' -f2-`
4. sort then remove smallest one which is in the first line `sort -n | sed  1d`
5. get the second column the make it serial `awk '{print $2}' | paste -s`